# Can I compress a log file from Jetty while it is being written

Tags: jetty

i want to compress the logger file today which the file is being written by the jetty server.  what I'm asking is, if I run this command

`gzip -c logger.file > logger.file.gz`

will it affect the jetty process that is logging? or is there any other way I can get the compressed file without disturbing the logging process of jetty java server.

Comment: Just in case: what is the OS?

Comment: It has a very good chance of success, but the clincher would be to just try it and examine the jetty `stderror.log`.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329385/compress-log4j-files

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The OS used is CentOS Linux